# Routing only some local IPs through VPN on dd-wrt

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, router, iproute2

Much similar to this entry: [Using DD-WRT to connect to VPN and Forward all traffic of certain devices through VPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/94283/using-dd-wrt-to-connect-to-vpn-and-forward-all-traffic-of-certain-devices-through) , I have set up my router with dd-wrt + OpenVPN to connect to a VPN. This works fine, and all traffic from behind the router goes through the VPN.

How do I route(?) traffic in the router so that only certain IPs from the LAN will go through the VPN, while the others take the "normal" route? Is it also possible to allow traffic from certain local IPs to go ONLY through the VPN, making it impossible for them to use the regular internet connection if the VPN is down?

I know this question was answered in the post I linked to, but that just doesn't seem to work for me. The routing table and rules change, but traffic still just goes through the VPN.

Comment: If you're adding the line `# ip rule add from 192.168.0.0/24 table 10` then all traffic on your subnet will get pushed to the VPN.  If you omit it and use only `# ip rule add from 192.168.0.3/32 table 10` with the IPs of the specific IPs you want to have be VPN only it should work fine.  If this is still an issue can you run `route` on the device and post the result?